# Python - Apply a filter on query using a Python Parameter

Tags: python, mysql, filter, cursor

I've a script that makes a query to my database on MySQL. And my doubt is if I can pass any parameter to that query through Python.

For example, on the following script I want to calculate the date_filter using Python and then apply that filter on the query.

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
date_filter = now - timedelta(days=3)

dq_connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass', host='localhost', database='db')
engine = create_engine('localhost/db')
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
query = ('''
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date >= ''' + date_filter + '''
''')
```

I try it on that way but I got the following error:

```
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str
```

It is possible to apply the filter like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. To avoid sql injections, the best way is not using the python formatting facilities, but the sql parameters & placeholders (see that you don´t need the single quotes ' as the placeholder does the job and converts the type of the variable):

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
date_filter = now - timedelta(days=3)

dq_connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass', host='localhost', database='db')
engine = create_engine('localhost/db')
cursor = db_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >=%s"
cursor.execute(query,(date_filter,))
```

Also, you had a mistake in your cursor, it should be db_connection.cursor. The last comma after date_filter is ok because you need to send a tuple.
In case you need more than one paremeter, you can place more than one placeholder:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >=%s and date<=%s"
cursor.execute(query,(date_filter,other_date))
```

Comment: grate answer :) Many thanks! Just a small question if instead of cursor.execute, I want to pass the data to a dataframe: df= pd.read_sql_query(query, connection) I can do it in the same way?

Comment: Yes you can do it as pd.read_sql_query(query,connection,params=(date_filter,)). You can read all sintax in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something like:

```py
WHERE date >= ''' + str(date_filter) + '''
```

to represent the date as string as not a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
date_f = str(date_filter)

query = ('''
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date >= "{}"
'''.format(date_f))
```